# conditional formatting Blank Cells Corresponding to Pivot Table

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I currently have a Pivot Table that is adjustable By a slice that Controls the length of rows of inputs.

```
Example: Filter:Animal
Chicken     Cow     Dog     Pig
5           4       3        2
```

I want to set  grid style formatting below the pivot table correspond to the Columns with values and will leave blank cells that are blank from the Slicer. How would I conditionally format cells with text and cells with out text to corresponding cell below? Creating a checklist.

I am currently using `=ISTEXT()` conditional formatting to get the grid formatting on all cells with text but when slicer is used it is not adjusting to length but can not adjust formula for a blank cell.

Comment: A picture of before and after may help. I'm having a hard time visualizing what you need

Comment: I want to add some conditional formatting with a custom formula that:

Changes the background color of cell A5 if Cell A1  is NOT empty and cell a5 is empty .                            But continued down the row so also changes the background color of B5 if cell B1 is NOT empty and B5 is empty. Cont through column G

Thanks.

Comment: Currently trying to use this: =AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A1)),ISBLANK(A5))

Comment: This is not working;/ could it be bc it is referring to a pivot table in A1?